# Adding a parameter to all HTTP requests in Angular

Tags: angular

I've a scenario whereby I need to update 150-200 methods in an existing angular project and add an extra parameter (boolean value) to the vast majority of the calls. I was thinking of maybe using something like an HTTP interceptor for this but from what I've read this does not appear to be something that an interceptor is made for.

Short of doing this by hand, does anyone know if there's a way of automatically adding an extra parameter to all requests generated by an Angular applcation?

Comment: One option might be to write your own "MyHTTP" service which uses the original HTTP service and adds the parameter.  Then finding and replacing all the previous uses should be a fairly simple global replace.

Comment: Interesting, had never considered that. Thanks

Comment: >this does not appear to be something that an interceptor is made for. 

I have to say.. I very much disagree with this. It's almost exactly what an interceptor is made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **HttpInterceptor** for achieve sending parameter for every http requests.
Use a reference in the following sites,

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/intro-to-angular-http-interceptors

https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8